# Optimizing a simulation in CUDA.jl

Tags: performance, cuda, julia, gpu

I'm trying to write a tutorial on GPU computing in Julia. Everything went fine when demonstrating simple matrix operations, with GPU blowing their single-threaded and multi-threaded equivalents out of the water.

Now I am trying to come up with a more complex example, involving the generation of simulated data `X` and the calculation of some estimate `β`, and that's when things get weird. No matter what I do, the GPU (Nvidia RTX 2070) simulation performs some 20 times worse than its multi-threaded (20) counterpart.

[image: benchmarks]

Here's some code for an MRE:

```
# Meta-simulation constants =================================
replications = 10
n = 100
p = 2
μ = rand(replications)

# Multi-threaded simulations =================================
β_par = fill(0., (p, replications))
function parsim()
  Threads.@threads for r in 1:replications
    X = rand(Float16, (n, p)) .* μ[r]; # Sample data
    β = sum(X .^ 2, dims = 1);   # Estimate parameters
    β_par[:, r] = β
  end
end

# GPU simulations =================================
using CUDA
β_gpu = CuArray(fill(0., (p, replications)))
function gpusim()
  for r in 1:replications
    X = CuArray(rand(Float16, (n, p))) .* μ[r]; # Sample data
    β = sum(X .^ 2, dims = 1);   # Estimate parameters
    β_par[:, r] = β
  end
end
```

I've spent over a dozen hours trying to get `gpusim()` to perform at least as well as `parsim()`. I've read the [CUDA.jl](https://cuda.juliagpu.org/) and [LinearAlgebra.jl](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/) docs countless times,
trying to figure out if I really needed to write my own kernel; After realizing I had little idea of what I was doing, I would try to find a simpler solution using linear algebra. Read more, got more confident, tried writing a kernel again. Rinse and repeat.

ChatGPT helped me find my bearings a bit, but its complicated solutions were no better than my naive `gpusim()` above.

Hopefully humans are still better at helping me understand how (and even if) I can get `gpusim()` to outperform `parsim()` for the task above.

Comment: I don't know Julia very well, so correct me if I'm wrong. In `parsim` you parallelize the `replications` loop while the `CuArray` works like a Numpy array, i.e. each operation is parallelized on the GPU. First of all your problem size seems way to small for a GPU make sense, even if you were able to parallelize over the full `n * p * replications` which is just 2000 i.e. way too small. If I interpret your code correctly, you only parallelize over 200. To feed a GPU you will need much bigger problem sizes.

Comment: Another reason might be that these calculations are bandwidth-bound. Is CUDA.jl able to perform automatic kernel fusion for rng, multiplication and reduction? If not you are paying for a lot of global memory reads and writes. To understand what is going on I would recommend looking at a Nsight Systems Trace.

Comment: So other than increasing problem size, I would recommend getting rid of the loop (i.e. start by generating a 3D `(n, p, replications)` array of random numbers and work from there) and then try to use something like `mapreduce` to fuse as many operations as possible. Ideally you want one big kernel so nothing other than the final `β_par` has to be written to global memory. I'm not sure if this is achievable with the array interface or if you will have to write your own kernel for that.

Comment: @paleonix, thank you for the tips! I've reduced the constants just for the MRE, but I'll try increasing the order of magnitude on my actual example. I've tried getting rid of the loop, but not the way you suggested (which sounds very promising). I'll post an answer if this gets me somewhere interesting, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tips from @paleonix and @loonatick, I was finally able to come up with a GPU function that performs as expected.

The trick, as I suspected but failed to implement, is to reformat the operations to minimize CPU-GPU communication and replace loops with matrix operations (mental note: use 3D arrays more often in my work).

I'm sure there are more improvements to be made to the solution below, but at least this gets the job done.

```
replications = 100
n = 100_000
p = 200
μ = rand(replications)

using CUDA
β_gpu = CUDA.fill(0., (1, p, replications))
μ_gpu = CuArray(reshape(repeat(μ, inner = n * p), (n, p, replications)))

function gpusim2!(β, n)
  p, reps = size(β)
  X = CUDA.rand(Float16, (n, p, replications)) .* μ_gpu # Sample data
  X² = X .^ 2
  β .= sum(X², dims = 1) # Estimate parameters
end
```

Using this and the code in the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76132128/1169233), this is the performance I get (using 20 CPU threads):

[image: benchmark]

I'm really happy that even with a small example I'm able to showcase the power of GPU computing. I've tried using the same tricks on my `seqsim()` function (not shown on this page, does sequential computation) and was able to double the performance, but it was still at a couple hundred ms.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get anywhere meaningful with GPU acceleration, I would strongly recommend starting with [NVIDIA's CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) to understand what exactly goes on when you have to perform computation on the GPU. There is a lot to unpack here, but let us just cover the basics.

Data has to be transferred to the GPU VRAM for performing computations. This data transfer is usually the main bottleneck. In your particular example,
`CuArray(rand(Float16, (n,p)))` generates random numbers in the CPU's memory, and then copies it over to the GPU VRAM in the `CuArray` constructor.

Similarly, `μ` is in CPU memory, and something like `x .* μ` will again have to copy a single scalar value from one memory region to another and then perform the computation, which is horribly inefficient.

There are also other problems with this code, such as using untyped global variables inside functions.

So, to fix the performance of your baseline GPU implementation.

1. Use `CUDA.rand` and `CUDA.fill` instead of `Base.rand` and `Base.fill` to generate data directly on the GPU.
2. Do not use global variables and pass data to functions instead (see [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/) in the docs).
3. Disallow scalar indexing in `CuArray`s using `CUDA.allowscalar(false)` (see [CUDA.jl docs](https://cuda.juliagpu.org/stable/usage/workflow/#UsageWorkflowScalar))

```
# Meta-simulation constants =================================
replications = 10
n = 100
p = 2
μ = rand(replications)

# GPU simulations =================================
using CUDA
β_gpu = CUDA.fill(0., (p, replications))
function gpusim!(β,n,μ)
    op,replications = size(β)
    for r in 1:replications
        X = CUDA.rand(Float16, (n, p)) .* μ[r]; # Sample data
        @views β[:,r] .= sum(X .^ 2, dims = 1)[:];   # Estimate parameters
    end
end
```

```
julia> @benchmark gpusim()
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 5600 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  725.984 μs … 108.525 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 25.07%
 Time  (median):     812.230 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   888.733 μs ±   2.795 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.07% ±  0.65%

                     ▁▂▃▃▂▂▂▁▃▆██▆▄▃                             
  ▁▁▂▃▆▆▇█▇▇▇█▅▆▆▇▇█▇███████████████▇▅▃▄▄▄▄▄▃▅▄▅▄▄▅▅▄▅▄▅▄▂▂▁▁▁▁ ▄
  726 μs           Histogram: frequency by time          921 μs <

 Memory estimate: 68.62 KiB, allocs estimate: 1251.

julia> @benchmark gpusim!(β_gpu,n,μ)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 7638 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  351.787 μs … 115.958 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 29.52%
 Time  (median):     570.030 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   650.441 μs ±   3.159 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  4.00% ±  0.82%

                                                  ▁▁▁▃▄█▆▂       
  ▂▃▃▂▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂▂▂▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▂▁▂▂▂▂▄▆▆▅▆▆▅▅▅▅▅▅▆▆██████████▆▅▅▄▃ ▃
  352 μs           Histogram: frequency by time          618 μs <

 Memory estimate: 73.12 KiB, allocs estimate: 1640.
```

**But, to be perfectly clear, this is still horrible performance; this particular algorithm can be written much more efficiently to exploit full GPU parallelism.**

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and tips! I can confirm the performance gain (2x over here) and the need for more refactoring until I reach more reasonable performance.